# How to upload multiple image file in a new generated folder in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, image

I was working on a project where a user can upload multiple images. everything is work fine but Now I want to create a new folder for every user with the custom name with date time just because people cannot overwrite there own image.

Like my every file is upload inside

> assets/uploads/

but I want to create a new folder for each user by there user id and upload there image inside that folder with date time rename.

```
|->assets|
        |
        |->uploads
                  |
                  |->1 (folder created by user id)
                  |
                  |->2 (folder created by user id)
```

here is my **model.py** code

```
 class Uqdetail(models.Model):
        uq_main_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        company_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        item_slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        item_image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

# ##### item_image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/'+UrgentQueryUserFolder+'/') (I try this by getting error)

        quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        unit = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
        moq = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        lead_time = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        payment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
        modified_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        deleted = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I was trying to write a function inside my model to get a current user id for creating user folder by passing that id but not helping to get error

```
def UrgentQueryUserFolder(self):
        user_id = self.id
        return user_id
```

Here is the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/an2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/an2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/an2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "/home/an2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/an2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/an2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/an2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/an2/office/s2s/s2s/urgentQuery/models.py", line 24, in <module>
    class Uqdetail(models.Model):
  File "/home/an2/office/s2s/s2s/urgentQuery/models.py", line 29, in Uqdetail
    item_image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/urgentQuery/'+UrgentQueryUserFolder+'/')
NameError: name 'UrgentQueryUserFolder' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/an2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'admin'
```

How can I create a new folder for each upload image user and also rename that image with new daytime and save that database to?

Comment: `I try this by getting error` which error exactly? Your upload_to function definition is illegal. Here is the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: just update the error

Comment: This error message is totally irrelevant to what you're asking about. Your app fails in `s2s/s2s/s2s/urls.py` when you're trying to refer to `admins` app which is `not installed`, which means, not listed in INSTALLED_APPS. Which has absolutely nothing to do with upload_to function and/or media files in general.

Comment: when I try to call the function then I get the error `item_image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/urgentQuery/'+UrgentQueryUserFolder+'/')`

Comment: just update my error that error code was wrong sorry for that

Comment: Please follow the link above. It has a well described example there.